# Mopub ads not showing

Tags: android, admob, proguard, mopub, millennial-media

I've been stuck on an issue for a while and I can't figure out what it is. The thing is I recently updated the *Mopub Android SDK* and both interstitial + banner ads (*AdMob* and *Millennial Media*) were working fine before that. Now these ads aren't working in the release build but they do work in debug build. So I think this is an issue with `proguard` but I can't trace what it is. The `proguard` is setup according to *Mopub* guidelines.

I have added the following to `proguard` for my project:

```
-keep class com.google.ads.**
-keep class com.millennialmedia.android.**
-keep public class com.mopub.mobileads.*
-keepclassmembers class com.millennialmedia.android.* {
public *;
}
```

In the release build, when I try to display an ad I get the following logs :

```
I/MoPub   (29856): Fetching ad network type: admob_native
D/MoPub   (29856): Loading custom event interstitial adapter.
D/MoPub   (29856): Attempting to invoke custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.GoogleAdMobInterstitial
D/MoPub   (29856): Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.GoogleAdMobInterstitial.

I/MoPub   (29856): Fetching ad network type: admob_native
D/MoPub   (29856): Loading custom event adapter.
D/MoPub   (29856): Attempting to invoke custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.GoogleAdMobBanner
D/MoPub   (29856): Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.GoogleAdMobBanner.
V/MoPub   (29856): MoPubErrorCode: Unable to find Native Network or Custom Event adapter.
```

Please suggest what the error might be. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Also I don't know if this is relevant or not but I'm working on a *Cocos2dx Android* project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It is `ProGuard` indeed. If you don't want it to "get rid" of `Mopub`, `AdMob` and `MMedia` code entirely, just put the following lines into `proguard-project.txt` file of your project:

```
    -keep class com.google.ads.** {*;}
    -keep class com.mopub.mobileads.** {*;}
    -keep class com.millennialmedia.android.** {*;}
    -keep class com.millennialmedia.google.** {*;}
```

Comment: Worked for me! Just had to include `-dontwarn com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit*` to have it working

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom native network and add your custom class in mopub site. Same with millennial and make sure you added necessary adaptors in your project.