# Android: Using MoPub mediation but Admob is reporting 0 impressions?

Tags: android, admob, ads, mopub

I setup mediation for my app several days ago using MoPub.  I currently have the Mopub Marketplace, Millennial Media and Admob setup.  However, Admob is reporting a ton of attempts but no impressions. They other networks seem to be working fine.  Has anyone experienced issues like this?

I do have proguard enabled...not sure if that might be the issue but I believe I correctly added the lines necessary to ensure the ads work.

Comment: I experienced similar issue with the MoPub/MM mediation. No impressions with lots of attempts. After setting up ProGuard appropriately i got to recieve impressions. That's [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591724/mopub-ads-not-showing/21923636#21923636) i set it up.

Comment: Hmmm thats how I currently have it...is it something to do with permissions? I didn't want to add the location permissions in. So I left those out.  Its only Admob not working.

Comment: Sorry, thought could help. I'm not using Admob with MoPub. Don't want to make any guess.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an AdMob support issue, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curious which particular credentials are you using? 
I only ask because within MoPub, you should be using your AdMob's 'Ad Unit ID' and not the 'Legacy Publisher ID.'  I know it may be confusing as within MoPub's dashboard it mentions to have the 'Publisher ID' but really it should be the 'Ad Unit ID' from AdMob that should be entered.

Please consult this guide for more info:  http://help.mopub.com/customer/portal/articles/1376821-how-to-set-up-updated-admob-revenue-reporting

Comment: That is probably the issue. Thank you so much