# Proguard export error in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, proguard

I am new to **proguard** and using proguard to application that uses millenium media ad sdk(mmedia) in eclipse.

I used the following statement `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt` in project.properties file.

**When exporting signed android app, i get the floowing error**

```
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find superclass or interface com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericCommand$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find superclass or interface com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$6: can't find superclass or interface com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find superclass or interface com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.pdx.PdxValue$Dictionary
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.pdx.PdxValue$Dictionary
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.pdx.PdxValue$Dictionary
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericCommand
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit$CmdSetType
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.DataBlock
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.DataBlock
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Data
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Data$DataType
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Data
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Action
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Action$ActionType
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Action$ActionType
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Action
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Action
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Data
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.DataBlock
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.DataBlock
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.recognitionresult.DetailedResult
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.recognitionresult.DetailedResult
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericCommand$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.pdx.PdxValue
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericCommand
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit$CmdSetType
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Data$DataType
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Action$ActionType
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericCommand$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand$Listener
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.pdx.PdxValue$Dictionary
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericCommand
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.DataBlock
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Data
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.util.dataupload.Action
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.recognitionresult.DetailedResult
    [2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.recognitionresult.DetailedResult
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.recognitionresult.DetailedResult
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer$Listener
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer$Listener
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$2: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$2: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericResult
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericCommand$Listener
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericResult
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericResult
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.GenericResult
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$3: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadResult
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand$Listener
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadResult
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadResult
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadResult
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$4: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.DataUploadCommand
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$6: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$6: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer$Listener
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$6: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$6: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$6: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$6: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$6: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$6: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$6: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Vocalizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$6: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognition
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer$Listener
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechKit
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognition
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.SpeechError
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognition
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognizer
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: com.millennialmedia.android.NVASpeechKit$7: can't find referenced class com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.Recognition
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] Warning: there were 154 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-04-12 04:10:05 - GestureLauncher]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Is there any solution for this problem,pls help

Thank you

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591724/mopub-ads-not-showing/21923636#21923636) and the comment to it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its printing warning , you can just avoid warning by Using the command `-dontwarn` in the proguard

ex

```
-dontwarn com.example.android.**
```