# MoPub 4.11.0 no ads

Tags: android, mopub

Currently I am upgrading MoPub in Android from 4.8.0 to 4.11.0. When I am debugging the app, ads are shown fine. When I generate a signed apk and deploy to a device, no ads are shown. All I did is change the dependency version. What can be the reason for this? Even upgrading it to 4.9.0 doesn't work

(note debugging the apk, ads are shown perfectly fine. When signing it, no ad events are being triggered like onBAnnerLoaded or onBannerFailed).

Comment: Seems like in release build the code is [obfuscated by `proguard`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591724/mopub-ads-not-showing/21923636#21923636).

Answer (score 0):

you can debug in two ways

1) In ADB logcat or console in Android studio , do you see the Ad call being made ? you can use a proxy Fiddler/Charles to see if your app is actually making the Ad call Or you can simply use the console in Android studio to look at the logs.

2) In the logcat look for the debugging information. In my App it looks like this, if there is an issue with loading it tells me Ad failed to load.

> 23:25:28.738                   MoPub  D  Loading url:
>   http://ads.mopub.com
>
> 23:25:29.453                          I  Ad failed to load.
>                               OR
>
> 23:25:29.453                          I  Ad loaded successfully.

Note: If you are unable to see the Ad call in the proxy or console then this points to a problem in your implementation.