# Admob - No mediation for test ads?

Tags: android, admob, ads

When I use real ads AND registering the device as a test device  - I **do** get test ads.

BUT if I use Google's test ads (*and also registering the device as a test device* ) - then I **don't** get test ads. (Error :  no mediators fill , 3)

I thought that google's test ads are always  there for me to test , regardless mediation.

**Question:**

Test Ads : Are those also affected by mediation ?

In other words - Is there any mediation differences between :

1 -  (Real ad + test device registration)
2 -  (Test ad + test device registration)
3 -  (Test ad + without  test device registration)

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18591724/3290339) help to some extend?

Comment: You should ask this question to admob support. https://support.google.com/admob/