# AdMob ads not showing in google play

Tags: android, google-play, admob, ads

**Ads show only in emulator and when I instal app from apk. But when I download this app from google play- ads not showing.**
OnCreate:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-8487255892576881~6132868827");

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    AdRequest ad = builder.build();
    mAdView.loadAd(ad);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8487255892576881/1584911850");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial.
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }

    });
```

Comment: This might be [ProGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18591724/3290339)

Comment: Same problems I have three apps before december 2018 these show ads but since December nothing